# Lost Update in ADO.NET and DataSets

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite, ado.net

I have two instances of a class called `User`. Each of these objects have their own DataSet, SQLiteConnection, SQLiteDataAdapter, etc. I'm trying to simulate a "Lost Update" anomaly here for school work.

The database table looks like this:

```
ID    Name     Salary
---------------------
1     John     10
```

The datasets are filled upon construction of the `User` objects. Each of these objects update the same row. The first object increases salary of row ID 1, by 2, resulting to 12. The second one also increases the salary by 5, resulting to 15, however we expected 17, or at least an exception, hence rollback of the transaction. But no exception happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the update code that I have in the `User` class

```
public bool IncreaseSalary(int raise) 
{
    int currentSalary = Convert.ToInt32(_dataSet.Tables["Employees"].
        Rows[0]["Salary"]);
    _dataSet.Tables["Employees"].Rows[0]["Salary"] = currentSalary + raise;

    _connection.Open();
    SQLiteTransaction transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
    _employeesDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    _employeesDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    _employeesDataAdapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    _employeesDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;

    int result = _employeesDataAdapter.Update(_dataSet);

    transaction.Commit();

    _dataSet.Clear();
    _employeesDataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);

    return result > 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to "simulate a Lost Update anomaly" then you have achieved it. Basically Lost Update means multiple "things" (entities, objects, etc) are trying to update the same single item (in this case a database row). The last update on that item is the one which is set. So in your case the Salary is 15, rather then 17, since the second `User` object was the last one to perform the update. Not sure if this explains what you're asking for though?

Comment: @JasonEvans Thanks. Yes, I guess I have achieved the anomaly. But now I have to demonstrate how I can deter this from happening and/or handle the situation in code.

Comment: Hmm, not sure to be honest, as you look to be using Transactions. Perhaps you need to re-design your code so that only one object can update the database? If that's not acceptable, then you need to look into `Pessimistic Locking` strategies for ADO.NET. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ *Optimistic Concurrency*. Specify the UpdateCommand to use where you can check for original values in case they have been changed by someone else. An example:

```
...
myAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Dept SET DeptNo = :DeptNo, DName = :DName WHERE DeptNo = :oldDeptNo", sqConnection); 
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("DeptNo", SQLiteType.Int32, 0, "DeptNo"); 
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("oldDeptNo", SQLiteType.Int32, 0, "DeptNo").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
...
```

After you call the update, check how many records have been affected; if none, then it's a *lost update*.